# How to type an object in typescript where the key is discriminator and value consists of a union?

Tags: typescript

Here is what I want to do:

```js
type Event = { type: string; };
type EventMapper<GenericEvent extends Event> = { [key: GenericEvent['type']]: (event: GenericEvent) => any };
type AddEvent = { type: 'add', name: string };
type RemoveEvent = { type: 'remove' };

const eventMap: EventMapper<AddEvent | RemoveEvent> = {
  add: (event: AddEvent) => null,
  remove: (event: RemoveEvent) => null,
};
```

I want the event parameter received by the event handlers to be narrowed using the discriminator. However, it throws `An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'` on `EventMapper` object definition. It doesn't narrow the event if I change to

```js
type EventMapper<GenericEvent extends Event> = { [key in GenericEvent['type']]: (event: GenericEvent) => any };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Event = { type: string; };
type EventMapper<GenericEvent extends Event> = 
  { [K in GenericEvent['type']]: (event: Extract<GenericEvent, {type: K}>) => any };
type AddEvent = { type: 'add', name: string };
type RemoveEvent = { type: 'remove' };

const eventMap: EventMapper<AddEvent | RemoveEvent> = {
  add: (event: AddEvent) => null,
  remove: (event: RemoveEvent) => null,
};
```

Core things to pay attention:

- `[K in GenericEvent['type']` - we say our key of the map will be type of `type` property value
- `(event: Extract<GenericEvent, {type: K}>)` - we say that function at given key will accept only member of the union with this key

The second is very important as without it every function argument would be generalized to `AddEvent | RemoveEvent`

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. Is there a book to understand advanced typescript typing (apart from the TS handbook)?

Comment: Nothing I can link to, but Blog of Marius Schulz is very good though